# Does GSVD implement all linear multivariate techniques?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, svd

I came across the article by [Hervé Abdi](http://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/Abdi-SVD2007-pretty.pdf) about generalized SVD. The author mentioned:

> The generalized SVD (GSVD) decomposes a rectangular matrix and takes into account constraints imposed on the rows and the columns of the matrix. The GSVD gives a weighted generalized least square estimate of a given matrix by a lower rank matrix and therefore, with an adequate choice of the constraints, the GSVD implements all linear multivariate techniques (e.g., canonical correlation, linear discriminant analysis, correspondence analysis, PLS-regression).

I'm wondering how the GSVD is related to all linear multivariate techniques (e.g., canonical correlation, linear discriminant analysis, correspondence analysis, PLS-regression).

Answer (score 2):

Section 4.1 of the article describes what the matrices, M and W, have to be for the generalized SVD to yield results comparable to correspondence analysis.  The author also cites his reference #3 to explain how the generalized SVD can yield results comparable to the other multivariate methods mentioned.

Comment: I have bookmarked this question very long ago. I would be very interested to see a clear and self-contained answer that might serve as a reference in the future. Do you think you can make it?